# ¿Por qué cambia la primera letra a mayúscula en los encabezados enviados desde Android a servidor PHP mediante Volley?

Tags: php, android

Estoy enviando una petición a una API (PHP) desde Android mediante Volley. En la petición van encabezados como estos:

```
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("apiKey", mAPIKey);
            headers.put("user", "usrName");
            headers.put("pwd", "myPass");
            headers.put("endpoint", "oraciones");
            headers.put("fecha", strFechaHoy);

            return headers;
        }
```

Resulta que en PHP recogía los encabezados con:

```
$arrHeaders=apache_request_headers();
```

Luego intentaba leer cualquiera de los datos pasados, por ejemplo:

```
$apiKey=$arrHeaders["apiKey"];
```

El código no encontraba el valor de  `apiKey`, porque las claves ponían la primera letra en mayúscula:

- `ApiKey`
- `User`
- `Pwd`
- `Endpoint`
- `Fecha`

**¿Saben a qué se debe esto? ¿Es algo que hace `Volley`, o bien ocurre al invocar `apache_request_headers()`?**

> En el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.apache-request-headers.php) no explica nada de esto, tampoco encontré
>   nada [revisando el código fuente de PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=apache_request_headers&unscoped_q=apache_request_headers).

Comment: No debería ser problema. Los headers HTTP son [case-insensitive](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). Si miras el código de algunos frameworks verás que suelen cambiar el nombre del header a minusculas [cuando los guardan](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros/blob/786cc5c4ac557ae59aaa1d36e885c90db789b29e/src/MessageTrait.php#L340).

Comment: Gracias @solarc, la cuestión es que aquí ocurre lo contrario, la primera letra se pone en mayúsculas y al buscar el valor con la clave como supuestamente lo he mandado me encuentro con que no funciona.

Comment: no es problema de `Volley` es del `apache_request_headers()`

Comment: al parecer aplica `Capitalized` a los headers pero los valores los deja intactos

Comment: @LPZadkiel lo curioso es que ni en el Manual de PHP, ni en el código fuente, aparece conversión alguna (ver pregunta editada al final).

Comment: pues muchos lenguajes de programación o librearías varias o frameworks no están bien documentadas e incluso los que si están bien documentados les puede faltar justo la información necesaria para algo específico que estas usando

Comment: @A.Cedano puedes chequear si la variable `$_SERVER` contiene los headers bien? Si no otra opción es usar un mitm como Fiddler o mitmproxy para ver que es lo que realmente llega/envia la aplicación.