# Como enviar un array de datos desde volley android a php

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

estoy haciendo una app con android studio utilizo volley para hacer peticiones al servidor remoto.
La app se trata de un control de inventarios, necesito que al presionar en el boton terminar inventario, se envie un array que contiene la informacion a guardar(con la idea de... inventario/detalle de inventario)

```
this.createInventario=(MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.enviarInventario);
    this.createInventario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cargarInventario(lista);
        }
    });
```

lista es un array que contiene items con la siguiente informacion, (codigo del producto, nombre del producto, cantidad, sector)..
cargarInventario(lista) tendria que mandar la lista esa al servidor, cargar la tabla inventario, despues cargar la tabla detalle de inventario con la lista recibida..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

metodo para para cargar(donde necesito mandar mi lista)

```
 private void cargarInventario(final JSONArray lista) {
    StringRequest request= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://stockalmacenmovil.000webhostapp.com/webService/inventario/createInventario.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                //recibe la respuesta del webservice cuando todo esta correcto
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Registrado")){

                        Toast.makeText(CreateInventario.this,"Registrado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     
    
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(CreateInventario.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateInventario.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        //enviamos los datos mediante post
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();
           //params.put("lista",lista.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    //requestQueue.add(request);
    //clase que crea una unica instancia
    VolleySingleton.getInstanciaVolley(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: Generalmente los datos se mandan creando un `HashMap` donde pones los pares clave:valor  a enviar. Si es una petición `GET` podrías probar a mandarlos en la URL (ese estilo no lo he probado, pero por definición del método `GET` debería funcionar). [Aquí hay un ejemplo de código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199626/29967) donde se envían datos al servidor mediante un `HashMap`.

Comment: si para cargar un producto o un un usuario mando los parametros con map<String,Strinng>.. osea datos para una sola tabla.. pero ahora quiero cargar datos en dos tablas.. tabla inventario(id_inventario,fecha,id_usuario) y detalleInventario(id_detalle,id_inventario,id_producto,cantidad,sector);

Comment: Entiendo, eso es más que nada un problema de lógica. Puedes por ejemplo mandar objetos anidados (un `HasMap` para una tabla y dentro otro `HashMap` con los datos) o enviar un solo `HashMap` e identificar cada dato por una clave, algo así: `dato1ParaTabla1 : valor; dato1ParaTabla2 : valor` y así, según la clave, sabrías a qué tabla va destinado.

Comment: y el detalle del inventario lo tengo almacenado en lista que es un array de inventarios..
ArrayList<clsInventario> lista=new ArrayList<>();
en la lista tengo cada uno de los items agregados.. osea que si yo registre 500 productos voy a tener una lista con 500 objetos.. a esos objetos necesito enviarlo.. para capturar con php y cargar la tabla inventarios y detalleinventario respectivamente.. espero que se entienda un poquito mas.. gracias