# Petición HTTP, el key de un header se transforma en minúscula. y eso no me funciona

Tags: html, angular, http, headers

Estoy intentado realizar una petición HTTP mediante POST. Esta petición necesita un header key-value con el key en mayúsculas obligatoriamente, pero cuando hago la petición esta se tranforma en minuscula haciendo que no funcione la petición. Lo estoy realizando con angular con el modulo de HttpClient.

```js
let cabecera = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('LACLAVE','11')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [A mí me pasaba algo parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199626/29967), pero en otro contexto. En mi caso lo que ocurría era que hacía un *capitalized* de las llaves. Nunca supe el motivo. Lo que hice fue convertir todo a minúscula y luego usar minúsculas para buscar los valores por sus llaves.

Comment: El problema es que esto se manda a un servidor que no controlo, y tampoco puedo capitalizarlas al otro lado, además de que es una combinación de mayúsculas y minúsculas... un lío muy grande vaya

Comment: En ese caso lo que puedes hacer es adaptarte a lo que hace el servidor, mandando las claves todo en minúscula ... o investigar si hay alguna forma, configurando los encabezados que mandas, de obligar al servidor a no convertir las claves, respetándolas como son enviadas. Quizá algún experto en Angular podría indicar si esto es posible y de qué modo.

Comment: De acuerdo con el estándar HTTP los nombres de las cabeceras son insensibles al caso (RFC 1626, apartado 4.2). O sea, que no puedes implementar una funcionalidad que dependa de que ciertos caracteres del nombre de una cabecera vayan en mayúscula o minúscula. Si haces algo así, estás incumpliendo el estándar y tendrás problemas con los clientes, servidores, proxies, etc. que lo siguen correctamente.