# No me inserta en mi Base de Datos XAMPP y sale que se guardo correctamente Android Studio Java

Tags: php, java, mysql, android-studio, xampp

estoy desarrollando un login en Android Studio con XAMPP y conectandose en PHP, y a la hora de desarrollar el registro de usuario, sale el mensaje de que se inserto correctamente en la app, pero al abrir el gestor de SQL aparece que no se cargo los datos, les adjunto la codificacion

Codigo JAVA

````
        public boolean Validacion(){
            
            if(ValiPass.equals(Vali2Pass)){
                ejecutar("http://MiIP/citasmedicas/registrar_usuarios.php");
    
    
            } else {
                RepeatPass.setError("La contrasena debe ser coincidir");
            }
    
            return returno;
    
        }
    
    
        private void ejecutar(String URL){
            StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "datos insertados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
    
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parametros= new HashMap<>();
                    parametros.put("nombre",Nombre.getText().toString());
                    parametros.put("apellido",Apellido.getText().toString());
                    parametros.put("fechanaci",FechaNac.getText().toString());
                    parametros.put("tipodoc",sDoc.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    parametros.put("nrodocu",DocNro.getText().toString());
                    parametros.put("sexo",selectsexo.getText().toString());
                    parametros.put("correo",Correo.getText().toString());
                    parametros.put("passw",Password.getText().toString());
                    return parametros;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegistroUsuario.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    
    }``  
Donde dice MiIP seria la direccion IP de mi maquina
Intente de varias formas para solucionar y sigue con el mismo problema, espero que puedan encontrar el causante del problema que teng

---

La codificacion del registrar_usuarios.php seria el siguiente
```<?php
$nombre=!empty($_POST['Nombre']) ? $_POST['Nombre']: NULL;
$apellido=!empty($_POST['Apellido']) ? $_POST['Apellido']: NULL;
$fechanaci=!empty($_POST['FechaNaci']) ? $_POST['FechaNaci']: NULL;
$tipodoc=!empty($_POST['Tip_Doc']) ? $_POST['Tip_Doc']: NULL;
$nrodocu=!empty($_POST['NroDoc'])? $_POST['NroDoc']: NULL;
$sexo=!empty($_POST['Sexo']) ? $_POST['Sexo'] : NULL;
$correo =!empty($_POST['Correo'])? $_POST['Correo'] : NULL;
$passw=$_POST!empty(['Password'])? $_POST['Password'] : NULL;

if ($nombre && $apellido && $fechanaci && $tipodoc && $nrodocu, && $sexo && $correo && $passw){
    $hostname="localhost";
    $port= "3306";
    $bd="db_citas";
    $pass="";
    $user="root";
    if($conexion=mysqli_connect($host,$port,$user,$pass,$bd)){
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
        $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios(Nombre,Apellido,FechaNaci,Tip_Doc,NroDoc,Sexo,Correo,Password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssss",$nombre,$apellido,$fechanaci,$tipodoc,$nrodocu,$sexo,$correo,$passw);
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $msg="Se han cargado exitosamente los datos"
            }else{
                $msg="Error en la carga : mysqli_error($stmt)";
            }
        } else{
            $msg="Error en la consulta {mtsqli_error($conexion)}";
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    } else {
        $msg="No se pueden guardar los datos"
    }
    echo $msg
}


?>
``
````

Comment: Hola, en el `onResponse` no estás comprobando nada, haces un `Toast` de forma ingenua, cuando lo que debes es verificar lo que hay en `response` para determinar si la inserción ocurrió realmente y para ello debes acoplar tu código de servidor donde manejas la inserción. ¿Podrías decirnos qué hay en `response` usando Logcat? ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta lo que hay en `registrar_usuarios.php`, evitando exponer datos sensibles?

Comment: No uses el área de respuestas para agregar contenido que es parte de la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega dicho contenido en la misma pregunta. Por otra parte, no nos has dicho qué imprime `response`, conviene que aprendas  a usar Logcat para depurar tu código. Aquí debes revisar sí o sí lo que está respondiendo el servidor.

Comment: Revisando el código PHP, aquí puede que sobre una coma que estaría produciendo un error 500 en el servidor: `$nrodocu, && $sexo` ... como te vengo diciendo, aprende a usar Logcat para depurar tu código, te vas a ahorrar muuuuchas horas (días) y muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Otro error, en el código PHP los parámetros no coinciden: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssss",$nombre,$apellido,$fechanaci,$tipodoc,$nrodocu,$sexo,$correo,$passw);` en la parte `"ssss"` debe haber un marcador de tipo de dato por cada valor. Son 8 valores, pero sólo tienes 4 marcadores. Recuerda que debes usar `i` en vez de `s` para los tipos que sean numéricos.

Comment: Más errores. Verifica cómo estás poniendo los parámetros en tu código Java, me refiero a `getParams()`. Allí, pones por ejemplo: `tipodoc` y  en PHP intentas recuperar  `$_POST['Tip_Doc']` lo mismo ocurre con `nrodocu` y  `$_POST['NroDoc']`, y mismo error con `passw` ... revisa eso y haz que coincida en cada caso. De la diferencia entre mayúsculas / minúsculas no me atrevo a decir nada, porque [en algún caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199626/29967) parece que Apache cambia la primera letra a mayúscula, pero no todo lo demás, como agregar `_` cuando no los hay.